# What is the recommended number for generating secure tokens in rails with SecureRandom.base64?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `SecureRandom.base64(16)`, but I'm not exactly sure if that's enough. I am also unsure what exactly the `16` means. I would have made a sensible guess that it's the number of random characters generated, but some tests disprove that.

E.g.

```rb
SecureRandom.base64(16)
=> "Hqncn1pVVHzoBJkFNpat4g==" # 22 characters, plus 2 equals signs at the end
```

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). For what purpose are you generating a secure token?

Comment: @JordanRunning I am using it to control use of an API. The API doesn't contain anything sensitive, but (thinking ahead) I want to be able to prevent abuse or ban badly behaved users. So I will have the token in the API urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is to be found in the [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-base64). Let me cite:

> `SecureRandom.base64` generates a random base64 string.
>
> The argument n specifies the length, in bytes, of the random number to
>   be generated. The length of the result string is about 4/3 of n.
>
> If n is not specified or is nil, 16 is assumed. It may be larger in
>   the future.
>
> The result may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, “+”, “/” and “=”.
>
> ```
> require 'securerandom'
>
> SecureRandom.base64 #=> "/2BuBuLf3+WfSKyQbRcc/A=="
> SecureRandom.base64 #=> "6BbW0pxO0YENxn38HMUbcQ=="
> ```
>
> If a secure random number generator is not available,
>   NotImplementedError is raised.
>
> See RFC 3548 for the definition of base64.

So you see that the `n` is the number of bytes your random number will have. The different length in the output string comes from converting that number into base64. The base64 encoding needs more bytes than an integer to store the same information.

If `n=16` is enough, depends on your specific use case. You may want to research how likely it is to produce a collision (two random number generations producing the same output) and how likely that results in a risk of your application.